# if len(list) in Python

Tags: python

I'm translating a Python code to C in order to take advantage of the parallelism available on HPC systems.
The original programmer used a conditional in Python that confuses me:

```
if rnum <> current_res:
    alim = 0
    if len(f): alim = f[-1]
```

What does `if len(f)` satisfy? I cannot find this convention used in this way anywhere online. I imagine it is a bad programming practice.

Comment: `<>` has long since been deprecated. Use `!=` instead.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Python, values that are considered 'empty', such as numeric `0`, are considered `False` in a boolean context, and otherwise are `True`.

Thus, `len(f)` is `True` if `f` has length, otherwise it is `False`. If `f` is a standard Python sequence type then the code can be simplified to:

```
if f: alim = f[-1]
```

because the same applies to sequences; empty is `False`, having a non-zero length means it's `True`. (Note that doesn't necessarily apply to non-builtin sequence types, only those that implement `__bool__` in this way.)

See [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the Python documentation for all the important details.

Note that `<>` has been deprecated; you should really use `!=` instead.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `len(f)` holds the same truth value as `f`? Surely it depends on `f`

Comment: @Awalias: **If** it is a custom sequence type then it is not safe to make that assumption.

Comment: @Awalias -- if `f` implements a custom `__nonzero__` (`__bool__` py3k) then they could be different, but that's a rare case.

Comment: It depends, of course, if `f` is a class I created and I override __len__ to return 4... it won't be the same. But then again I should be beaten with a stick if I did.

Comment: @pcalcao -- If you've not done anything with `__nonzero__` it will be the same.

Answer (score 11):

In most cases `if len(f):` will be the same thing as `if f:`...

the reason is because if `f` has no length, it will return `0` which is a falsy value.  Actually, truth testing actually checks the length of an object (`__len__`) [under some circumstances.](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__)

Answer (score 7):

This

```
if len(f)
```

would translate to:

```
if len(f) != 0
```

or in this case, since `len(f)` is never negative,

```
if len(f) > 0
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, only `!= 0`, but since you can't have a negative length sequence, it's not functionally relevant.

Comment: @sr2222,  I've clarified the answer.  They are equivalent here, since the example is `len`, and I included it because `len > 0` is more readable.

Comment: @sr2222 -- But could you have a negative length other object?  The docs say the result *should* be an `integer >= 0`, but I don't know that means that it's enforced or just expected...

Comment: -0.  The pythonic idiom would be `if f:`.

Comment: @mgilson heh, in the unexpected case I suppose `len > 0` is the best option :P

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, sure, there could be a non-conforming object that returns a negative number from `__len__`.  Or a string.  Or a database connection object.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski The question is about converting to `C`, not making old python code more pythonic.

Comment: @askewchan:  Does C even have empty/not empty semantics?  It does have `sizeof`, but that has nothing to do with the state of the array, only its size.  (disclaimer:  I don't know C.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I haven't used C in many years either, but due to the use case, I just thought it would be helpful to make the statement more explicit rather than more pythonically idomatic as the other two answers did.  Obviously my opinion differs from all others'.

Comment: @askewchan: Good point.  I think the most important thing to point out is that `f` is being tested to see if it is empty.  That's the concept that needs to be ported.