# count letters in a loop and break with a special char

Tags: python

I have a small problem here, i´m developing a program for children with special care so can they learn the ABC and a basic math with first contact with a PC, this one requests the user to input a string in a loop and counts the times that we insert a word, in my case i provide the letter "a". and sums every letter in the final

So the problem is that my code isn't breaking the loop if we input the "." it doesn't stop and not counting correctly, does it misses a sum ? i cant figure it out what is wrong and not understand why it´s not stopping
thank you for all the help

```
while True: 
    string = input("Insert the text :> " )
count = 0
for x in string :
    if x == "a":
        count = count + 1
        continue
    if x == ".":
        break
print("the count is" +str(count))
```

when the program is running i input the examples under

```
> Insert the text :> banana  
1 1 1 
Insert the text :> after 
1 
Insert the text :> . 
the count is  0
```

the expected is to sum all the letters at the end, and gives to me when i put a word e returns the number of A´
for example

```
input banana 3 
input after 1
the count is 4
```

Comment: Where are the `1`s after the input-lines currently printed - or is this just your wish?
Seems like the example output is resulting from answered code and the expected is what you want. Note: after you input text and hit enter, there will be a newline, so counts will appear on a newline.

Comment: Hello hc
this is only a example, the 1´s its what the program prints and the objective is to show how many chars is in the word, instead showing me 1 1 1 shows 3 letters, at the end it as to show in count 3 not zero wich is appending now

Answer (score 2):

Like Oliver said, you need to put everything in the while loop. However, you also need to break out of the while loop. I would do it with a variable like so.

```
running = True
while running: 
    string = input("Insert the text :> " )
    count = 0
    for x in string :
        if x == "a":
            count = count + 1
            continue
        if x == ".":
            running = False
print("the count is" + str(count))
```

Comment: Thank you Gabe, now i understand the importance to put inside the while, now we solved one of the problems, now ill go for the second part where i have to count the "A"´s that it stills missing, maybe i will try to put a sum no  ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```py
searchLetter = "a"
stopLetter = "."
totalCount = 0

while True:
    string = input("Insert the text :> ")
    subCount = string.count(searchLetter)
    totalCount += subCount
    if string.count(stopLetter) != 0:
        break
    print(subCount)

print("The count is " + str(totalCount))
```

We're using built-in [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20count#str.count) function to see how many times a letter appears in a given word or line.

If the stopLetter (in this case `.`) appears, we instantly break out of the while loop. Otherwise, we keep accepting input.

Comment: Hi Gabe, no problem, your first code work well for me the only issue is that when put a word it prints 1 1 1 instead 3, at the end when we input the "." it prints the count is zero, that´s why i ask if we need a sum 


where is the print
Insert the text :> santas
1
2
Insert the text :> .
the count is  0

Comment: Great answer! Could also pre-define empty input as `s = ''` to simplify exit-condition as `while not s.count(stopLetter):` because [0 is falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905282/if-lenlist-in-python). In the loop `s` becomes user's input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all of your code inside the `while` loop:

```py
while True: 
    string = input("Insert the text :> " )
    count = 0
    for x in string :
        if x == "a":
            count = count + 1
            continue
        if x == ".":
            break
    print("the count is" +str(count))
```

Comment: hello 
thank you for your answer i review the code and continues the loop, something is missing

Comment: This solutions has issue because of the ```break```. You have used ```break``` inside the ```for loop```. So, when your code encounters ```break```, it only break from the ```for loop```, not the ```while loop```. ```break``` statement always breaks only the loop it is in, not the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering counting every alphabet and asking the user to input a letter to find out how many times it appears, you can use a built-in function called `Counter` from the `collections` library.

```
from collections import Counter

while True:
    string = input("Insert the text :> " )

    if string == ".":
        break

    dictionary = Counter(string.lower())
    answer = input("Press 'y' to start counting!")
    while answer.lower() == 'y':
        letter = input("What letter do you want to check? ")
        print("the count is" , dictionary[letter])
        answer = input("Do you wish to continue to check the letter? [y/n]")
```

Comment: Hello Kevin
i terms of future update i will use your kind of code, so can they use and learn everything, at this point i only want to use the letter A, so can put every word they know using A, it stops and give a score to everyone one, at the end it will count the letters, now the issue is only finishing the count witch is showing me 0

Comment: Understood, in that case, just feel free to go on with the other answers provided :D

Answer (score 0):

The range of answers is all struggling with exit-condition and char-counting, including UI-improvements and case-sensitivity.

#### Divide and Conquer

I thought it would help to split you project into small isolated and testable functions. This way you can:

- find bugs easier next time
- easily extend for new features

#### Solution

```
def count_char(s, char, stop_char):
    count = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter == stop_char:
            return None
        elif letter == char:
            count = count + 1
    return count


def ask_and_count(letter, stop_char):
    s = input("Counting '{letter}'s for your input (enter {stop_char} to quit):")
    counted = count_char(s, letter, stop_char)
    if counted is None:
        return None
    print(f"Counted {counted} 'a's.")
    return counted


letter = 'a'
stop_char = '.'
runs = 0
while runs >= 0:
    # debug-print:  print(f"Run #: {runs}")
    count = ask_and_count(letter, stop_char)
    if count is None:
        break     # alternatively set runs = -1
{total}")
    total += counted
    # debug-print:  print(f"Run #: {runs} + Counted: {count} = Total: 

# Loop exited because user entered stop_char
print(f"Runs: {runs}, Total sum of '{letter}'s counted: {total}.")
```

This was the console dump for a test-run:

```
Counting 'a's for your input (enter . to quit): a
Counted 1.
Counting 'a's for your input (enter . to quit): aa
Counted 2.
Counting 'a's for your input (enter . to quit): bcdaaa
Counted 3.
Counting 'a's for your input (enter . to quit): a.a
Counted 2 when finding stop-char. Will quit without adding and display previous total.
Runs: 4. Total sum of 'a's counted: 6.
```

#### Useful patterns

1. defined a lot of functions (learn about `def` keyword *arguments* and `return`)
2. the exit-condition has now 2 alternatives: `break     # alternatively set runs = -1`
3. plenty of informal printing done using *f-strings* (very useful, since Python 3.6)
4. added features: parameterised chars, run counter, improved UI